# removing single letter words using java pattern matching

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want to eliminate all single letter words from a string in Java using pattern matching. I've coded as follows:

```
    String str = "P@";

    //remove single char words and extra white spaces
    inputStr = inputStr.replaceAll("\\b[\\w']{1}\\b", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
```

I'm expecting an output as P@ as the input is not a single letter word. But I'm getting output as @ because its eliminating P. So basically its considering only alphabetical characters for matching pattern. Whereas I want to match on the basis of length of the string entered.

Please help.

Comment: The problem seems to be `\b`, which does not count @ as a letter.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this :

```
        String data = "asd df R# $R $$ $ 435 4ee 4";

    String replaceAll = data.replaceAll("(\\s.\\s)|(\\s.$)", " ");
    System.out.println(replaceAll);
```

Output is : `asd df R# $R $$ 435 4ee`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
str = str.replaceAll("(^.$|\\s.\\s|^.\\s|\\s.$)", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
```

The problem with your solution was that you were using `\b` which was expecting a character at the end and start of word so it was not working in your case.

`/b`

Matches at the position between a word character (anything matched by \w) and a non-word character (anything matched by [^\w] or \W) as well as at the start and/or end of the string if the first and/or last characters in the string are word characters.

[**REFER FOR REGULAR EXPRESSION**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)

Comment: This is not a complete solution. Its a solution only for the mentioned example. Because if I change my string to "P", this will retain it as it is. But as I said, I want to eliminate single letter words.

Comment: This solution does not take into account words that are not enclosed in whitespaces. (For instance words at the start/end of the string, or words followed by comma or period).

Comment: @brimborium OP has mentioned that he needs the actual length of the string to be considered including other characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
\s([^\s]{1})\s
```

Should catch single character non-whitespace, delimited by a whitespace on either side. If you need to accept non-whitespace characters like ',' and '.' as delimiters you will need to add those.

Answer (score 0):

The test case is: 
**asd df R# $R $$ $ 435 4ee 4 hey buddy this is a test i@ wanted**

```
"[!-~]?\\b[A-z]\\b[!-~]?"
"[!-~]?\\b[\\w]\\b[!-~]?"
```

the output for above code is:

**asd df   $$ $ 435 4ee 4 hey buddy this is  test  wanted**
**asd df   $$ $ 435 4ee  hey buddy this is  test  wanted**
notice that in the second one the four is missing. The second regex gets rid of numbers didn't know if a single number counted or not